Change Poetry Python version
Context

I want Poetry to use Python 3.12.x
Poetry is installed globally, and I've set Pyenv to default to 3.12 globally on my machine
I'm using VSCode
In the terminal in my project, I've done poetry env use 3.12, and poetry install which successfully created a venv and installed my dependencies
Within VSCode I manually selected the python interpreter within that new venv

Unexpected behavior
When I do poetry debug info I get the following:
Poetry
Version: 1.8.2
Python:  3.11.4

Virtualenv
Python:         3.12.1
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/user/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-LrBQS-9F-py3.12
Executable:     /Users/user/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-LrBQS-9F-py3.12/bin/python
Valid:          True

Base
Platform:   darwin
OS:         posix
Python:     3.12.1
Path:       /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1
Executable: /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/bin/python3.12

Question
Why does "Poetry" report version 3.11.4? How can I specify ^3.12?
Version 3.11 is not my global Python, it's not the version of the interpreter my VSCode is using (or by extension the interpreter in the active venv), and I don't have any dependencies that require 3.11.

Here are some instructions that might be useful]

When you create the Poerty environment, the python version has been specified.
The vscode python interpreter cannot modify this setting. You can try to install a new Poerty environment by command poetry env use 3.12 or modify the pyproject.toml file such as adding the following codes:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"

